# error while running cloned nodejs project in my laptop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

hi sorry to say again another problem when i cloned a project from github in my PC and while running the project given error shows.Does anyone has solution for this?"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" bin\www
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object. (c:\Users\MohammadWahedul\chirp\module-5\completed\app.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Did you clone from a repo that has a package.json file?
If so, try running "npm i" from the project root.

Comment: yes I cloned from a rep which includes package.json and i did run npm i but no solution :(